# Swift not fetching data Firebase RTDB

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I seem to have encountered an error with fetching data from Firebase.

My goal is to observe the jobs collection for any live updates, and the code below throws an error:

```
    func fetchJobs() {
    ref.child("jobposts").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
        
        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]  else { return}
        
        var job = JobData()
        
        job.title = (dictionary["title"] as! String) <-- Error Here
        job.company = (dictionary["company"] as! String)
        job.city = (dictionary["city"] as! String)
        job.salary = (dictionary["salary"] as! String)
        job.creator = (dictionary["creator"] as! String)
        
        self.jobs.append(job)
        
    }
}
```

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

The weird thing is, that this worked before and i'm not sure what happened, im just starting to understand SwiftUI after all :D

My Firebase database looks like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance for all the suggestions and possible solutions! <3

EDIT: Result from print(dictionary):

```
["-MkmZtye53DPpWb0-Wsn": {
city = 123;
company = 123;
creator = 8NHEiFMaCdSlEsBwuBw5oWrArOh1;
salary = Test;
title = 123;
```

}]

Comment: One of your items *does not* have a `title` property. See [What does "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Comment: Seems weird, because everything seems to be correct. If i delete the listing, the app seems to be working, but when i add a new one it just crashes...

Comment: Can you update the question with the result of `print(dictionary)`?

Comment: Your `title` is not a `String`. It's an `Int`. Thus, casting it to `String` fails.

Comment: Added the edit. 
P.S. the same happens with any value in title

Comment: Note the types of all of the fields. You're using `Int` but trying to cast them all to `String`. This will always fail. It doesn't happen with "any value" in the title -- it happens when you don't use Strings.

Comment: Just tried creating a listing without any Integers, same problem persists.

Comment: Can you print the result of the dictionary that doesn't have an `Int`s?

Comment: First test `dictionary["title"]` if it's nil, and then if it's a String, etc, for each one. But it maybe be more interesting to soft unwrap with `if let`...

Comment: ["-MkmZtye53DPpWb0-Wsn": {
    city = abc;
    company = abc;
    creator = 8NHEiFMaCdSlEsBwuBw5oWrArOh1;
    salary = Test;
    title = abc;
}]

Comment: And it still crashes on the same line? Sounds suspicious...

Comment: I know! The thing is, maybe i should use a different approach? I just need the app to be able to see the change in values in realtime

Comment: What happens if you try to cast to `[String:String]` on your `guard` statement? Does it work or fail?

Comment: Seems to have worked, but the Jobs are not getting appended now, any idea why?

Comment: It's getting to `jobs.append` but it's not appending? Where are you checking to see whether it's been appended?

Comment: I have a different view where the listing are being shown, its empty while using the [String:String]

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't answer the question of where you are checking. Without seeing the code to see how they're being displayed, it's impossible to debug.

Comment: @jnpdx https://pastebin.com/NTz86Fry Thats the view i use to get the values
The card template: https://pastebin.com/He9J0SdG

Comment: That's not compilable code for me. You'd need to create a [mre]. Or, at least show `SessionStore`.

Comment: The SessionStore: https://pastebin.com/kQp2knuy

Comment: Sorry -- too much to dig through and unrelated non-compilable code. I'd suggest trying to create a [mre] in a new question.